# Call URL with authentification Header in Java

Tags: java, http-headers

Im essentially trying to call a URL with an access token in Java without success. Using just terminal i can do it without any problems

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://api.typeform.com/forms/{form_id}/responses?since=2017-07-09T00%3A00%3A00&until=2017-07-10T00%3A00%3A00' \
  --header 'authorization: bearer {your_access_token}'
```

I tried this in Java without success:

```
try {
            URL u = new URL(resulturl2);
            c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setRequestProperty("authorization",apitoken);
            c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
            c.setUseCaches(false);
            //c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            c.setConnectTimeout(8000);
            c.setReadTimeout(8000);
            c.connect();
            int status = c.getResponseCode();
}catch(IOException e){

        }
```

Any suggestions are really apreciated!

Comment: Define "without success".  Do you get an error?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `"bearer " + apiToken`?  (And *never* write an empty `catch` block—print the stack trace if you want to know what’s going wrong!)

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I needed to change `c.setRequestProperty("authorization",apitoken);` to `c.setRequestProperty("authorization","bearer "+apitoken);` and it worked